# Ubuntu 14.04 as compared to Linux Mint 17

Tags: mint

Can I expect comparable performance and compatibility with my laptop as far as software center and ppa's under Mint as I do in trusty. I suppose I can use VirtualBox to experiment. I know this is question is somewhat on the line, but I will try anyway.

Comment: Linux Mint is a [derivative](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeTeam/Derivatives#Customizations-2) of Ubuntu - it is based on the same packages, some of which have been replaced with new one to make a customized version.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try a VBox install to test it

Comment: IMHO, Ubuntu and Linux Mint are pretty much close under the hood. The performance of graphical interface depends on couple factors : your GPU, the desktop environment you use, the amount of ram. Of course hardware and drivers for them play role as well. Most software for ubuntu is available under Mint,too

Comment: Just found this which is similar: [Difference between Ubuntu and Linux Mint](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46833/difference-between-ubuntu-and-linux-mint). Probably needs updating anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux Mint is a [derivative](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeTeam/Derivatives#Customizations-2) of Ubuntu - it is based on the same packages, some of which have been replaced with new one to make a customized version. You can sort of see this by looking at the repositories list on it:
[image]
<sup>This is from the Live DVD - probably not much different to the installed version</sup>

Looking at http://packages.linuxmint.com/list.php?release=Qiana it seems to be mainly cinnamon, Xfce, & Mate desktop mods along with some themes - though it probably influences some more system related things such as graphics drivers as Mint is supposed to have a more open approach to proprietary software.

Comment: I installed Mint 17 Cinnamon in VBox this AM it's actually nice. I like it better it unity that's for sure, but it's setup like old windows, meh, I've been a Mac user since 1989, never used Windows computers, got a free quad core i5/8gb/512ssd Dell, I'm trying to find a distro that resembles OSX but is pure Linux with all the support that comes with Ubuntu. Maybe Vivid will be more to my liking.

Comment: @Todd - if you want it to look/work somewhat like a Mac you can use the default Unity interface in Ubuntu, and add themes and stuff http://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-1404-mac-zukimac-theme/ . Mint uses cinnamon by default which is sort of trying to act like Windowz :)

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. I feel like I should end this discussion for fear of down votes.